# Contar cuantas veces se repite una palabra en una matriz en javascript y aplicarle un condicional

Tags: javascript

Me encuentro con el siguiente problema:

Escribí un código que toma como punto de partida una matriz con 2 valores: "ocupado" y "libre" en relacion a la disponibilidad de una determinada butaca de cine.

Mi codigo funciona correctamente con un doble ciclo for y me devuelve si hay o no hay butacas disponibles en cada una de las filas, pero me encuentro con este problema.

Como puedo agregarle a este codigo un condicional que me permita saber la cantidad EXACTA de butacas disponibles en cada fila?

```js
let butacasCine = [
  ['ocupado', 'libre', 'libre', 'ocupado'],
  ['libre', 'libre', 'libre', 'ocupado'],
  ['libre', 'libre', 'ocupado', 'ocupado'],
  ['ocupado', 'ocupado', 'ocupado', 'ocupado'],
  ['libre', 'libre', 'libre', 'ocupado'],
];

let butacasDisponibles = false;

for (let i = 0; i < butacasCine.length; i++) {
  butacasDisponibles = false;
  for (let j = 0; j < butacasCine[i].length; j++) {
    if (butacasCine[i][j] === 'libre') {
      butacasDisponibles = true;
    }
  }
  if (butacasDisponibles === true) {
    console.log(`En la fila ${i} hay butacas libres`);
  } else {
    console.log(`Todas las butacas de la fila ${i} se encuentran ocupadas`);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siguiendo en base a tu solución, podrías inicializar un array para que acumule la cantidad de butacas libres que hay por fila, cuando entre a la condición de que si **`butacasDisponibles`** es **`true`**, contamos la longitud del array y luego se eliminarán los elementos para que no se incremente la longitud por cada ciclo **`for`** y de esta forma volverá a contar los repetidos para cada fila:

```js
let butacasCine = [
  ['ocupado', 'libre', 'libre', 'ocupado'],
  ['libre', 'libre', 'libre', 'ocupado'],
  ['libre', 'libre', 'ocupado', 'ocupado'],
  ['ocupado', 'ocupado', 'ocupado', 'ocupado'],
  ['libre', 'libre', 'libre', 'ocupado'],
];

let butacasDisponibles = false;
let contarButacasLibres = []; // inicializamos un array

for (let i = 0; i < butacasCine.length; i++) {
  butacasDisponibles = false;
  for (let j = 0; j < butacasCine[i].length; j++) {
    if (butacasCine[i][j].includes('libre')) {
      butacasDisponibles = true;
      contarButacasLibres.push([i]); // pusheamos la cantidad de repetidos
    }
  }
  if (butacasDisponibles === true) {
    console.log(`En la fila ${i} hay ${contarButacasLibres.length} butacas libres`); // contamos los reptidos
    contarButacasLibres = []; // seteamos a 0 al array
  } else {
    console.log(`Todas las butacas de la fila ${i} se encuentran ocupadas`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Me encantó esta resolución! Muchas gracias!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Una posible solución puede ser la siguiente:

1. Recorrer todas las butacas y usar el método `filter` para buscar aquellas que estén libre

```js
let butacasCine = [
    ['ocupado', 'libre', 'libre', 'ocupado'],
    ['libre', 'libre', 'libre', 'ocupado'],
    ['libre', 'libre', 'ocupado', 'ocupado'],
    ['ocupado', 'ocupado', 'ocupado', 'ocupado'],
    ['libre', 'libre', 'libre', 'ocupado'],
];


let butacasLibre = butacasCine.map((butaca, index) => {
    // Obtenemos solo las butacas que estan libre
    let libre = butaca.filter(butacaFila => butacaFila == 'libre')
    return {
        index: index,
        libre: libre.length //Simplemente mostramos el total de butacas libres
    }
})
butacasLibre.forEach((bLibre) => {
    if (bLibre.libre == 0) {
        console.log(`Todas las butacas de la fila ${bLibre.index} se encuentran ocupadas`)
    } else {
        console.log(`En la fila ${bLibre.index} hay un total de ${bLibre.libre} butacas libre`);
    }
})
```

Como ves el resultado es el mismo, pero es mas legible y no tal complejo.

Answer (score 0):

Donde validas si hay una butaca libre, puede sumar +1 cada vez.

```js
// El contador global
total_butacas_libres = 0
por_fila = {}
   

let butacasCine = [
  ['ocupado', 'libre', 'libre', 'ocupado'],
  ['libre', 'libre', 'libre', 'ocupado'],
  ['libre', 'libre', 'ocupado', 'ocupado'],
  ['ocupado', 'ocupado', 'ocupado', 'ocupado'],
  ['libre', 'libre', 'libre', 'ocupado'],
];

let butacasDisponibles = false;

for (let i = 0; i < butacasCine.length; i++) {
  console.log(i)
  butacasDisponibles = false;
  for (let j = 0; j <= butacasCine[i].length; j++) {
    //Agregamos todas las filas al contador
    if(!por_fila[i])por_fila[i]=0
    if (butacasCine[i][j] === 'libre') {
      butacasDisponibles = true;
      //Aquí vamos acumulando. 
      total_butacas_libres++
      //Por cada fila
      por_fila[i]++
    }
  }
  if (butacasDisponibles === true) {
    console.log(`En la fila ${i} hay butacas libres`);
    
  } else {
    console.log(`Todas las butacas de la fila ${i} se encuentran ocupadas`);
  }
}


console.log({total_butacas_libres})
console.log({por_fila})
```